# Making the solutions of a ParametricNDSolveValue show up as different colours?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions, style

I am having a bit of trouble when it comes to plotting the solution of a system of **non-linear ODE's**.

I write

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  system, {x[t], y[t], z[t], px[t], py[t], pz[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, {tau, 
   omega, xi, yi, zi, pxi, pyi, pzi}]
```

- *xi, yi, zi, pxi, pyi, pzi* are the **initial conditions**
- *tau* and *omega* are just two **other parameters**

This gives me a single parametric function as the output.

I then write

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[pfun[tau0, omega0, xi0, yi0, zi0, pxi0, pyi0, pzi0], {t, 0, 
   1}], {{tau0, 0.5, "strength"}, 0, 1}, {{omega0, 2 Pi}, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {{xi0, 1, "initial theta"}, 0, Pi}, {{yi0, 1, "initial phi"},
   0, 2 Pi}, {{zi0, 1 , "initial phase"}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{pxi0, 1}, -Pi , 
  Pi}, {{pyi0, 1}, -Pi, Pi}, {{pzi0, 1}, -Pi, Pi}]
```

Which does correctly plot a bunch of solutions, with parameters that I can vary, however, I cannot then **make the different plots show up in different colours**!
 [image]

Could anyone explain what I need to do?

I have tried to use things like "Plot Style" in the third argument of the "Plot" function, but this does not work.

Edit:

I will copy and paste a full simple example that causes me the same issue as described above.

```
$Assumptions = {x, y, tau, xi, yi} ∈ Reals

system = {D[x[t], t] == (Cos[x[t]] y[t])/tau, 
  D[y[t], t] == (Sin[y[t]] x[t])/tau, x[0] == xi, y[0] == yi}

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  system, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, {tau, xi, yi}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[pfun[tau0, xi0, yi0], {t, 0, 1}], {{tau0, 0.5, "strength"}, 0, 
  1}, {{xi0, 1, "initial theta"}, 0, 
  Pi}, {{yi0, 1, "initial phi"}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Can you make a simpler case where you could provide a complete example? Hard to duplicate your problem otherwise.

Comment: Yes; I will include a simpler case by editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `Evaluate` command before `pfun`

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@pfun[tau0, xi0, yi0], {t, 0, 1}], 
           {{tau0, 0.5,  "strength"}, 0, 1}, 
           {{xi0, 1, "initial theta"}, 0, Pi}, 
           {{yi0, 1, "initial phi"}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This worked for the main problem also! Could you please explain why we should use the Evaluate command here? What is Mathematica thinking when we include it vs when we do not. Apologies; I am very new to this.

Comment: It is quirky. With the `Evaluate` command, the values of (for example) `pfun[1,1,1]` are determined immediately and you get your two functions to plot, then `t` is set. Otherwise a `Plot` command holds the function to be plotted in an unevaluated form until the independent variable is set, so `t` is set first then the `pfun[1,1,1]` is evaluated. That is enough to puzzle the line coloring algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    Manipulate[Plot[{pfun[tau0, xi0, yi0][[1]], pfun[tau0, xi0, yi0] 
              [[2]]}, {t, 0,  1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
              ImageSize -> Medium], {{tau0, 0.5, "strength"}, 0, 
              1}, {{xi0, 1, "initial theta"}, 0, Pi}, {{yi0, 1, "initialphi"}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer seems the simplest to understand: We use the first set of square brackets on pfun to turn the single parametric function into a list of interpolating functions, then use the second double square brackets to pick out each one of the interpolating functions from the list?!

Comment: @monday I think it is more-so just the use of the double-bracketed version of `Part` that helps in this case. The "first set of square brackets" is merely accessing the function using those arguments. Although with the way you defined `pfun`, it is easy to see where the confusion comes into being.